# Travelling with twins

Tags: air-travel, lhr, brisbane

My daughter, who lives in Queensland, had identical twin girls in February 2018. She would like to visit home, the UK. Would it be possible for her to travel from Brisbane to Heathrow by herself with the babies?

Comment: In addition to @ZachLipton's answer below, note that all airlines I know of allow only one free infant lap child per adult passenger. She will need to book at least two tickets, with an approved infant seat for the second child.

Comment: That would be a really tough trip. Some helpful hints: https://www.parents.com/baby/twins/raising/flying-with-twins/

Comment: Maybe it would be easier Mom to visit her? :)

Answer (score 7):

It's certainly allowed—no regulations would prohibit such a trip unless a doctor has advised otherwise—, but flying from Brisbane to London is an extremely long trip: 23+ hours each way with at least one stop. That's an exhausting trip for a parent traveling alone with two very young babies, and many parents may not want to or be able to undertake such a journey.

Comment: Less than 6 month olds (pre-crawling) are probably a lot less of a problem than later.

Answer (score 6):

Brand new to the forum and this is my first post but I may have some valuable input given my travel history with my children when they were young. 
Yes, it is possible for your daughter to travel with two babies that are a couple of months old. I am not aware of any restrictions so long as the babies are healthy.
That said, that is an awfully long flight, and they will likely be exposed to many things on the airplane, so that is one consideration.
If she is bringing any sort of car seat/travel seat, have her call the airline and get it pre-approved. I had a seat that was fine for most airlines, but one suddenly refused it.

Be prepared for an unexpected layover. Weather, airline equipment delays, etc. may set her back. It means packing lots of extra stuff for the babies in case of emergency, but you really don't want to be without if you get stuck somewhere for a day. Extra diapers, changes of clothes, and formula if she's not breastfeeding. Also, some of the water from home if she is using formula.

Beyond that, be prepared for her fellow passengers to
be less than pleased when she boards with the infants.
It's a long flight and people want to get some shuteye. Some will be wonderfully helpful, and some will try to move their seat as far away as possible.

It can be done, but much
easier for family/mother/father/sister/ to go to her, if possible.